# Spacetime metric as an order parameter?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor, phase-transition, emergent-properties

I've been reading on Sean Carroll's ideas ([1], [2]) on space from Hilbert space and bulk entanglement gravity in which he tries (and succeds) to derive the linearized Einstein equation directly from a vector in Hilbert space. 
In the meantime, I've been learning about Laundau-Ginzburg's theory of second order phase transitions and how they are described by an order parameter.

This got me wondering, could spacetime be a broken symmetry state of the underlying quantum states which underwent a phase transition? The order parameter might be the metric itself. You go from a non-geometric state (therefore 0 metric) to a geometric one (non-vanishing metric) analogously to the development of an order prameter in regular condensed matter physics.

If that is the case what might be the symmetry that is broken? Can this high level ideea be concretized into mathematical form somehow? I would like to see if it leads somewhere, so any hints on implementing the math or criticism is welcomed!

**References:**
 [1] arXiv:1606.08444
 [2] arXiv:1712.02803